# Adding the same cell onto itself in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to add two values from two cells , A & B and then update that in B. Basically, it is B=A+B. Is it possible in Excel? Using VBA?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Trying using like this

```
Sub Add()
   
    Range("C9").Value = Range("C9").Value + Range("D9").Value
    
End Sub
```